# Searching an associative Array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Hi I have following array

```
Array
(
 [k1] => Array
        (
            [0] => banana
            [1] => mango
            [2] => orange
            [3] => orange
        )

    [k2] => Array
        (
            [0] => adaL
            [1] => ada
            [2] => dad
            [3] => dad
        )
)
```

Now I want to remove duplicate entries like ORANGE. How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$a = array_map('array_unique', $a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
$k1 = array('banana', 'mango', 'orange', 'orange');
$k1 = array_unique($k1);
```

Which will give you

```
array
  0 => string 'banana' (length=6)
  1 => string 'mango' (length=5)
  2 => string 'orange' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value = array_unique($value);
}
```

Comment: Please always include the `unset($value)` after the `foreach` when using references like that. Otherwise we know what the next question on the site will be. ;)